# Regex to get part from delimiter to end of the string excluding that delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

Got string like `somedomen.com/path::targettext/with/params` and trying to get only `targettext/with/params` **without** `::` or no match if no delimiter found.

Using `/:{2}.*$` returns text with delimiter (`::targettext/with/params`)

and using `/(?!=::)[^:]*$` returns whole string if it has no delimiter.

Using Javascript.

Can anybody help?

Comment: which flavour or regex, i.e. which language ?

Comment: Using Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this in javascript, it will also work in any languge:

```
.*?::(.*)$
```

you get your desired result in group 1

```js
const regex = /.*?::(.*)$/gm;
const str = `somedomen.com/path::targettext/with/params`;
let m;

if((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this pattern:

```
/::(.*$)/
```

And then `$1` contains what you need.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BlriCQ/3)

Comment: `\K` is not supported in javascript

Comment: @Gurman True, but why do you think the author wants this pattern for JS ?

Comment: Because he mentioned it in the question

Comment: @Gurman Oh, right, wasn't see it before. thanks for the heads up